# How to parse と世界観の中で

Tags: grammar

I'm having a little trouble parsing the phrase in question in the following sentence:

> ベンテン、イダテン、アドン、サムソンなどの個性の強いキャラクターがこれまた個性の強い相手と世界観の中で繰り広げるハチャメチャな内容。

Taken from the [back of this videogame's box](https://gamefaqs1.cbsistatic.com/box/9/8/1/102981_back.jpg).

*An absurd tale where Benten, Idaten, Adon, Samson and other peculiarly individual characters are facing off against peculiarly individual foes.*
A rather free translation but I suppose it gets the point across (minus the phrase in question, of course). I'm not exactly sure how「世界観」fits into the equation here. I've looked the word up and found following:

> １ 世界およびその中で生きている人間に対して、人間のありかたという点からみた統一的な解釈、意義づけ。知的なものにとどまらず、情意的な評価が加わり、人生観よりも含むものが大きい。楽天観・厭世 (えんせい) 観・運命論・宗教的世界観・道徳的世界観などの立場がある。
> ２ 俗に、文学・音楽などで、その作品がもつ雰囲気や状況設定。「人気漫画の世界観が楽しめるカフェ」

I don't think I'm exactly sure what I'm looking for. If I'm not mistaken number one describes the *world view* one has and number two describes the *atmosphere / appearance of something* e.g. of a fictional work. I'm not sure how to interpret either of these into the sentence above though as I'm missing a modifier for「世界観」.

Googling the phrase, I found another sentence which seems to employ the same structure:

> 『スター・ウォーズ／銀河の英雄』は、SWのキャラと世界観の中で冒険するRPG(vﾟ∀ﾟ)v

Taken from [this blog post](http://girlsnight.no-uragawa.net/archives/2266/).

Again I'm missing the modifier as to what kind of「世界観」I'm looking at here.「SWのキャラと冒険する」->「どういう世界観の中でSWのキャラと冒険する？」

I assume「世界観」is trying to highlight the unique setting these works are set in but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it grammatically.

Answer (score 2):

> ベンテン、イダテン、アドン、サムソンなどの個性の強いキャラクターがこれまた個性の強い相手と世界観の中で繰り広げるハチャメチャな内容。

What modifies "世界観" is "個性の強い."
So, you can rewrite this to:

> ベンテン、イダテン、アドン、サムソンなどの個性の強いキャラクターがこれまた個性の強い相手と**個性の強い世界観**の中で繰り広げるハチャメチャな内容。

Similarly,

> 『スター・ウォーズ／銀河の英雄』は、SWのキャラと世界観の中で冒険するRPG(vﾟ∀ﾟ)v

in this case, what modifies "世界観" is "SWの."
You can rewrite this to:

> 『スター・ウォーズ／銀河の英雄』は、SWのキャラと**SWの世界観**の中で冒険するRPG(vﾟ∀ﾟ)v

Well, kimi Tanaka pointed this case, but I think the issue is not difficult context, just the simple  modification rule of "AとB."

MのAとB = MのAとMのB

Comment: Funnily enough that is how I initially justified the whole thing for myself but grammar-wise it sounded kinda wrong, looks like I was on the right track after all though, good to know! Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. 世界およびその中で生きている人間に対して、人間のありかたという点からみた統一的な解釈、意義づけ。知的なものにとどまらず、情意的な評価が加わり、人生観よりも含むものが大きい。楽天観・厭世 (えんせい) 観・運命論・宗教的世界観・道徳的世界観などの立場がある。

I think this definition is more of a one's philosophical perspective/thought.

> ２ 俗に、文学・音楽などで、その作品がもつ雰囲気や状況設定。「人気漫画の世界観が楽しめるカフェ」

I believe this definition (2) still holds to your example.

> ベンテン、イダテン、アドン、サムソンなどの個性の強いキャラクターがこれまた個性の強い相手と世界観の中で繰り広げるハチャメチャな内容。

And, I think the characters in the video game package shows their unusual appearances as bodybuilders at a glance. Rather than describing the their personality in detail, the videogame creator probably wants to show "what it is" and ambience of the game in the package and impress the consumers immediately.

For grammar,

> 『スター・ウォーズ／銀河の英雄』は、SWのキャラと(その/SWの)世界観の中で冒険するRPG(vﾟ∀ﾟ)v

In Japanese language, we often do not use definite article at all. So you may sometimes need to read the context and add some articles/determiner (i.e.「その」or 「SWの」 in the parenthesis I added in the sentence) when you are reading.

> ベンテン、イダテン、アドン、サムソンなどの個性の強いキャラクターがこれまた個性の強い相手と(こういう)世界観の中で繰り広げるハチャメチャな内容。

It's bit hard for me to parse this sentence with momentum. I will add (こういう) : this sort of in the sentence if necessary.

Comment: Just like I already replied to Spoonail above, thank you very much for the confirmation! It is an odd structure indeed, I can't recall having ever come across it so far, at least I never made a mental note of it. Interesting to know.